# Running Gretty project with Gradle Docker container

Tags: java, docker, gradle, build, gretty

Is it possible to run [Gretty](https://github.com/akhikhl/gretty#readme) projects in [Docker Gradle](https://hub.docker.com/_/gradle) container?

Normally the Gretty task `tomcatRun` starts Tomcat app server and you can browse the app at http://localhost:8080/app-name. With Docker Gradle image the task is successfully started but the container is terminated immediately after that.

Steps for reproducing the issue:

1. [Install Docker](https://www.docker.com/get-started).
2. Clone https://github.com/haba713/hello_gretty.
3. `cd hello_gretty`
4. Install Gradle wrapper:
   `docker run --rm -u gradle -v "$PWD":/home/gradle/project -w /home/gradle/project gradle gradle wrapper`
5. Run the task `tomcatRun`: `./gradlew tomcatRun`
6. Browse http://localhost:8080/hello_gretty.
7. Terminate the task by pressing enter in terminal.
8. Run task `tomcatRun` with Gradle Docker image:
   `docker run --rm -u gradle -p 8080:8080 -v "$PWD":/home/gradle/project -w /home/gradle/project gradle gradle tomcatRun`
9. The task `tomcatRun` is started (takes some time) but for some reason the
   container terminates immediately after that. Maybe the task was completed
   without pressing any key.

I also created a [Docker issue](https://github.com/docker-library/official-images/issues/7348) about the problem.

Comment: If the task is waiting on input, does launching the container with `-it` help?  Why are you using this really roundabout path of launching unmodified Gradle via Docker?

Comment: `-it` helped. Thanks a lot! My goal is to find an easy way for front-end developers to build and start Java back-end without installing Java, Gradle etc. With this solution we don't need separate containers for building and running the service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `-t` or `--tty` to `docker` command keeps Tomcat running. Also add `-i` or `--interactive` if you want to stop Tomcat with "any key" as Gretty says: "Press any key to stop the server."

`docker run --rm -u gradle -it -p 8080:8080 -v "$PWD":/home/gradle/project -w /home/gradle/project gradle gradle tomcatRun`

Thank you [David Maze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10008173/david-maze) for helping.